# localhost working,online not working in android

Tags: php, android

Hi I am designing Chat application using this index.php,But localhost working perfertly when I was move to online it's not working.how to know the server port.In client side I am calling this index.php file.

Can any one please help me

**index.php**

```
<?php


    require_once("mysql.class.php");


    $dbHost = "xxx";
    $dbUsername = "xxx";
    $dbPassword = "xxxx";
    $dbName = "xxx";


    $db = new MySQL($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);


    define("FAILED", 0);

    define("SUCCESSFUL", 1);

    define("SIGN_UP_USERNAME_CRASHED", 2);  

    define("ADD_NEW_USERNAME_NOT_FOUND", 2);


    define("TIME_INTERVAL_FOR_USER_STATUS", 60);

    define("USER_APPROVED", 1);
    define("USER_UNAPPROVED", 0);


    $username = (isset($_REQUEST['username']) && count($_REQUEST['username']) > 0) 
                                ? $_REQUEST['username'] 
                                : NULL;
    $password = isset($_REQUEST['password']) ? md5($_REQUEST['password']) : NULL;
    $port = isset($_REQUEST['port']) ? $_REQUEST['port'] : NULL;

    $action = isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : NULL;
    if ($action == "testWebAPI")
    {
        if ($db->testconnection()){
        echo SUCCESSFUL;
        exit;
        }else{
        echo FAILED;
        exit;
        }
    }

    if ($username == NULL || $password == NULL)  
    {
        echo FAILED;
        exit;
    }

    $out = NULL;

    error_log($action."\r\n", 3, "error.log");
    switch($action) 
    {

        case "authenticateUser":


            if ($userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password)) 
            {                   



                $sql = "select u.Id, u.username, (NOW()-u.authenticationTime) as authenticateTimeDifference, u.IP, 
                                            f.providerId, f.requestId, f.status, u.port 
                                from friends f
                                left join users u on 
                                            u.Id = if ( f.providerId = ".$userId.", f.requestId, f.providerId ) 
                                where (f.providerId = ".$userId." and f.status=".USER_APPROVED.")  or 
                                             f.requestId = ".$userId." ";



                $sqlmessage = "SELECT m.id, m.fromuid, m.touid, m.sentdt, m.read, m.readdt, m.messagetext, u.username from messages m \n"
        . "left join users u on u.Id = m.fromuid WHERE `touid` = ".$userId." AND `read` = 0 LIMIT 0, 30 ";


                if ($result = $db->query($sql))         
                {
                        $out .= "<data>"; 
                        $out .= "<user userKey='".$userId."' />";
                        while ($row = $db->fetchObject($result))
                        {
                            $status = "offline";
                            if (((int)$row->status) == USER_UNAPPROVED)
                            {
                                $status = "unApproved";
                            }
                            else if (((int)$row->authenticateTimeDifference) < TIME_INTERVAL_FOR_USER_STATUS)
                            {
                                $status = "online";

                            }
                            $out .= "<friend  username = '".$row->username."'  status='".$status."' IP='".$row->IP."' userKey = '".$row->Id."'  port='".$row->port."'/>";



                        }
                            if ($resultmessage = $db->query($sqlmessage))           
                                {
                                while ($rowmessage = $db->fetchObject($resultmessage))
                                    {
                                    $out .= "<message  from='".$rowmessage->username."'  sendt='".$rowmessage->sentdt."' text='".$rowmessage->messagetext."' />";
                                    $sqlendmsg = "UPDATE `messages` SET `read` = 1, `readdt` = '".DATE("Y-m-d H:i")."' WHERE `messages`.`id` = ".$rowmessage->id.";";
                                    $db->query($sqlendmsg);
                                    }
                                }
                        $out .= "</data>";
                }
                else
                {
                    $out = FAILED;
                }           
            }
            else
            {

                    $out = FAILED;
            }



        break;

        case "signUpUser":
            if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
            {
                 $email = $_REQUEST['email'];       

                 $sql = "select Id from  users 
                                where username = '".$username."' limit 1";



                 if ($result = $db->query($sql))
                 {
                        if ($db->numRows($result) == 0) 
                        {
                                $sql = "insert into users(username, password, email)
                                    values ('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."') ";                          

                                    error_log("$sql", 3 , "error_log");
                                if ($db->query($sql))   
                                {
                                        $out = SUCCESSFUL;
                                }               
                                else {
                                        $out = FAILED;
                                }                           
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $out = SIGN_UP_USERNAME_CRASHED;
                        }
                 }                      
            }
            else
            {
                $out = FAILED;
            }   
        break;

        case "sendMessage":
        if ($userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password)) 
            {   
            if (isset($_REQUEST['to']))
            {
                 $tousername = $_REQUEST['to']; 
                 $message = $_REQUEST['message'];   

                 $sqlto = "select Id from  users where username = '".$tousername."' limit 1";



                        if ($resultto = $db->query($sqlto))         
                        {
                            while ($rowto = $db->fetchObject($resultto))
                            {
                                $uto = $rowto->Id;
                            }
                            $sql22 = "INSERT INTO `messages` (`fromuid`, `touid`, `sentdt`, `messagetext`) VALUES ('".$userId."', '".$uto."', '".DATE("Y-m-d H:i")."', '".$message."');";                       

                                    error_log("$sql22", 3 , "error_log");
                                if ($db->query($sql22)) 
                                {
                                        $out = SUCCESSFUL;
                                }               
                                else {
                                        $out = FAILED;
                                }                       
                            $resultto = NULL;
                        }   

            $sqlto = NULL;
            }
            }
            else
            {
                $out = FAILED;
            }   
        break;

        case "addNewFriend":
            $userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password);
            if ($userId != NULL)
            {

                if (isset($_REQUEST['friendUserName']))         
                {               
                     $friendUserName = $_REQUEST['friendUserName'];

                     $sql = "select Id from users 
                                     where username='".$friendUserName."' 
                                     limit 1";
                     if ($result = $db->query($sql))
                     {
                            if ($row = $db->fetchObject($result))
                            {
                                 $requestId = $row->Id;

                                 if ($row->Id != $userId)
                                 {
                                         $sql = "insert into friends(providerId, requestId, status)
                                             values(".$userId.", ".$requestId.", ".USER_UNAPPROVED.")";

                                         if ($db->query($sql))
                                         {
                                                $out = SUCCESSFUL;
                                         }
                                         else
                                         {
                                                $out = FAILED;
                                         }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $out = FAILED;  
                                }                                                
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $out = FAILED;                      
                            }
                     }                               
                     else
                     {
                            $out = FAILED;
                     }              
                }
                else
                {
                        $out = FAILED;
                }           
            }
            else
            {
                $out = FAILED;
            }   
        break;

        case "responseOfFriendReqs":
            $userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password);
            if ($userId != NULL)
            {
                $sqlApprove = NULL;
                $sqlDiscard = NULL;
                if (isset($_REQUEST['approvedFriends']))
                {
                      $friendNames = split(",", $_REQUEST['approvedFriends']);
                      $friendCount = count($friendNames);
                      $friendNamesQueryPart = NULL;
                      for ($i = 0; $i < $friendCount; $i++)
                      {
                        if (strlen($friendNames[$i]) > 0)
                        {
                            if ($i > 0 )
                            {
                                $friendNamesQueryPart .= ",";
                            }

                            $friendNamesQueryPart .= "'".$friendNames[$i]."'";

                        }               

                      }
                      if ($friendNamesQueryPart != NULL)
                      {
                        $sqlApprove = "update friends set status = ".USER_APPROVED."
                                        where requestId = ".$userId." and 
                                                    providerId in (select Id from users where username in (".$friendNamesQueryPart."));
                                    ";      
                      }

                }
                if (isset($_REQUEST['discardedFriends']))
                {
                        $friendNames = split(",", $_REQUEST['discardedFriends']);
                      $friendCount = count($friendNames);
                      $friendNamesQueryPart = NULL;
                      for ($i = 0; $i < $friendCount; $i++)
                      {
                        if (strlen($friendNames[$i]) > 0)
                        {
                            if ($i > 0 )
                            {
                                $friendNamesQueryPart .= ",";
                            }

                            $friendNamesQueryPart .= "'".$friendNames[$i]."'";

                        }                   
                      }
                      if ($friendNamesQueryPart != NULL)
                      {
                        $sqlDiscard = "delete from friends 
                                            where requestId = ".$userId." and 
                                                        providerId in (select Id from users where username in (".$friendNamesQueryPart."));
                                                ";
                      }                     
                }
                if (  ($sqlApprove != NULL ? $db->query($sqlApprove) : true) &&
                            ($sqlDiscard != NULL ? $db->query($sqlDiscard) : true) 
                   )
                {
                    $out = SUCCESSFUL;
                }
                else
                {
                    $out = FAILED;
                }       
            }
            else
            {
                $out = FAILED;
            }
        break;

        default:
            $out = FAILED;      
            break;  
    }

    echo $out;



    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function authenticateUser($db, $username, $password)
    {

        $sql22 = "select * from users 
                        where username = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."' 
                        limit 1";

        $out = NULL;
        if ($result22 = $db->query($sql22))
        {
            if ($row22 = $db->fetchObject($result22))
            {
                    $out = $row22->Id;

                    $sql22 = "update users set authenticationTime = NOW(), 
                                                                     IP = '".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."' ,
                                                                     port = 15145 
                                    where Id = ".$row22->Id."
                                    limit 1";

                    $db->query($sql22);             


            }       
        }

        return $out;
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: signup user and authentication user and returning 0

Comment: Hi kiren siva help me

Comment: when u connect to network u mean localhost doesnot work is it?

Comment: No it's working in localhost.and main hosting into server it's not working

Comment: ok u mean when u move service to remote its not working ..did u cheacked the config file?

Comment: where all server configuration is been setted like u setted for localhost in ur php code above..btw what does "mysql.class.php" contains?

Comment: databaseusername: user1 password: user1 port: 21 action: signUpUserout: 0

Comment: running into browser it's giving like this

Comment: m still confuse what error u r getting did u chnaged this --> $dbHost = "xxx";
    $dbUsername = "xxx";
    $dbPassword = "xxxx";
    $dbName = "xxx";
?? for ur sever config?

Comment: yes that file works fine

Comment: the error u r getting take a screenshot and post it on some public image share and post the link here

Comment: Please take that webservice URL in a browser and know the result

Comment: for testing fwrite($myfile, "out: ".$out); by passing the parm action=signupuser it giving 0

Comment: same like that i did showing 0

Comment: Whenever posting a question, please just include the relevant parts. Or at least a pseudo of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is at the dbHost variable, for the connection beetwen the devices, it needs to have an IP Adress, i asume you had LocalHost at the dbHost before and thats why it was working, so the solution is getting the IP adress of the Data base that you are using for the app and placing it on the code. Of course it's not recommended for you to use an static IP on the host, because if the IP of the database changes you will have to re-write the dbHost value with the new IP

Comment: Can you please give some example

Comment: $dbHost = "192.168.1.101";
    $dbUsername = "user";
    $dbPassword = "";
    $dbName = "dbChat";